# Erro de método indefinido em tabela não retorna métodos getteres

Tags: php

Estava fazendo umas mudanças do no meu código, mudanças essas que eram a visibilidade dos atributos da classe (mudei os atributos de public para private e estou usando os metodos getters e setters)

Só que está o ocorrendo o seguinte erro no trecho da `Tabela de listagem`.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAluno() on array
```

- Classe `Aluno`

```
abstract class Aluno extends BD {
        
        protected $tabela;
        private $cd_aluno, $nome, $endereco;

        public function getAluno() {
            return $this->cd_aluno;
        }

        public function getNome() {
            return $this->nome;
        }

        public function getEndereco() {
            return $this->endereco;
        }

        public function setAluno($cd_aluno) {
            $this->cd_aluno = $cd_aluno;
        }

        public function setNome($nome) {
            $this->nome = $nome;
        }
        
        public function setEndereco($endereco) {
            $this->endereco = $endereco;
        }
    }
```

- Classe `CrudAluno`

```
class CrudAluno extends Aluno{

   protected $tabela = 'aluno'; 

   public function Select() {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->tabela";
     $stm = BD::prepare($sql);
     $stm->execute();
     return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }
}
```

- Tabela de listagem

```
<table id="lista" border="1">
        <tr> 
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Nome </th>
            <th> Endereço </th>
            <th> Ações </th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            foreach ($aluno->Select() as $key){
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$key->getAluno().'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$key->getNome().'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$key->getEndereco().'</td>';
                echo '<td>'."<a href='/crud/formulario/form_atualizar.php/#atualizar'>Atualizar</a> ".
                "<a href='/crud/formulario/form_excluir.php/#excluir'>Excluir</a>".'</td>';
                echo '</tr>'; echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: `$aluno->Select()` retorna um `array` de `arrays`. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando faz o foreach:

> foreach ($aluno->Select() as $key)

O que está nomeado como key na verdade é value, no momento cada $key é o array com o conteudo de uma linha no BD;

Se quiser pegar a key também (index na contagem das linhas dos resultados), deve fazer:

> foreach ($aluno->Select() as $key => $value)

Mas isso ainda não é o problema em questão, o erro acontece porque está tentando rodar a função getAluno() como se ela estivesse dentro de um resultado no banco de dados, quando na verdade essa função está em uma classe que você escreveu, ela não se comunica automaticamente dessa forma.

Dentro desse foreach você não precisa usar as funções da classe para obter os dados pode simplesmente fazer:

```
<?php
foreach ($aluno->Select() as $value){
    //...
    echo '<td>'.$value['nomeDaColunaNoDb'].'</td>';
    //...
}
```

OBS.: Ao usar o parametro `FETCH_ASSOC` para obter os dados, você vai obter array ao invés de objeto, então deve usar `$meuArray['chave']`, para obter algum dado e não `->`.

Se quer ter acesso as funções da sua classe `Aluno` ao usar o `Select` da classe `DB`, seu método `Select` não pode retornar os resultados, ele deve organiza-los na classe e retornar `$this` ou um objeto para que possa usar métodos a partir dos resultados, mas é necessário criar uma lógica para gerenciar esses vários resultados, por exemplo usando uma classe instanciável para cada resultado ao invés de abstrata e retornar a classe após usar os métodos de definir os dados.